# search for a specific value in text files

Tags: vb.net

I have to lists with a number of variants. sample of first list

List 1)

hkdhksa 
 OP-ID: 111112 
 jklfjdlkfsd 
 hfldhfjksdf 
 OP-ID: 111113 
 ghjg 
 OP-ID: 111114 
 OP-ID: 111115 
 gjgjhghgjhg  
 OP-ID: 111116 
 OP-ID: 111117
 OP-ID: 111118

List 2)

OP-ID: 111112 
 OP-ID: 11113
 OP-ID: 111114
 OP-ID: 111115 
OP-ID: 111117

Result would be: OP-ID: 11118 is not in List 2

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Declare two dictionaries. The key for each will be 
    ' the text from the input line up to,
    'but not including the first ",". 
    ' The valus for each will be the entire input line.

    'Dim file1 As New HashSet(Of String) '!
    Dim file1 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim file2 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TEST1)
        Dim part() As String = line.Split(",")

        If line = ("OP-ID: ") Like "OP-ID:*" Then
            If Not file1.ContainsKey(part(0)) Then file1.Add(part(0), line)
        End If

    Next

    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TEST2)
        Dim part() As String = line.Split(",")
        If Not file2.ContainsKey(part(0)) Then file2.Add(part(0), line) '!
    Next


    Dim keysInList1ThatAreNotInList2 = file1.Keys.Except(file2.Keys)
    Dim values = From key In keysInList1ThatAreNotInList2 Select file1(key)
    Dim str = String.Join(vbCrLf, values)

    txtResults.Text = ("IDs should not be in list: " & str)

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your code doing or not doing?  Also your code is reading lines of text but your sample shows the data for each one in one line.  You need to show the data in the exact format you're using.

Comment: see above edieted lists how they look in text files

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using a dictionary when you're only dealing with one field.  Each value has the same key and dictionaries must have unique keys.  A Simple List(Of String) should work well:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim file1 As New List(Of String)
    Dim file2 As New List(Of String)
    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TEST1)
        If line.StartsWith("OP-ID:") Then
            Dim temp As String = line.Split(" "c)(1)
            If Not file1.Contains(temp) Then
                file1.Add(temp)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TEST2)
        If line.StartsWith("OP-ID:") Then
            Dim temp As String = line.Split(" "c)(1)
            If Not file2.Contains(temp) Then
                file2.Add(temp)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Dim keysInList1ThatAreNotInList2() As String = file1.Except(file2).ToArray
    Dim str = String.Join(vbCrLf, keysInList1ThatAreNotInList2)
    txtResults.Text = ("IDs should not be in list: " & vbCrLf & str)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample lists don't have any commas, and it's not clear from the question whether they exist or not.

**If there are no commas**:

If there are no duplicates in `TEST1` (or you don't care about them):

```
Dim hs As New Hashset(Of String)(File.ReadLines(TEST1))
hs.ExceptWith(File.ReadLines(TEST2))
txtResults.Text = $"IDs not in list:{vbCrLf}{String.Join(vbCrLf, hs)}"
```

If the duplicates are important:

```
Dim hs As New Hashset(Of String)(File.ReadLines(TEST2))
Dim notFound = File.ReadLines(TEST1).Where(Function(x) Not hs.Contains(x)).ToList
txtResults.Text = $"IDs not in list:{vbCrLf}{String.Join(vbCrLf, notFound)}"
```

---

**If there are commas**

(Shared code)

```
Dim keyParser = Function(x As String)
        Dim indexOf = s.IndexOf(
        If indexOf = -1 Then Return x
        Return Left(x, indexOf)
    End Function
Dim list2Keys = New Hashset(Of String)(File.ReadLines(TEST2).Select(keyParser))
```

If there are no duplicate keys in `TEST1`:

```
Dim list1 = File.ReadLines(TEST1).ToDictionary(keyParser)
Dim notFound = list1.Where(Function(kvp) Not list2Keys.Contains(kvp.Key)).Select(Function(kvp) kvp.Value)
txtResults.Text = $"IDs not in list:{vbCrLf}{String.Join(vbCrLf, notFound)}"
```

If there are duplicate keys in `TEST1`, but they don't matter:

```
Dim list1 = File.ReadLines(TEST1).ToLookup(keyParser)
Dim notFound = list1.Where(Function(grp) Not list2Keys.Contains(grp.Key)).Select(Function(grp) grp.First)
txtResults.Text = $"IDs not in list:{vbCrLf}{String.Join(vbCrLf, notFound)}"
```

If the duplicate keys in `TEST1` do matter:

```
Dim list1 = File.ReadLines(TEST1).ToLookup(keyParser)
Dim notFound = list1.Where(Function(grp) Not list2Keys.Contains(grp.Key)).SelectMany(Function(grp) grp)
txtResults.Text = $"IDs not in list:{vbCrLf}{String.Join(vbCrLf, notFound)}"
```